# Tomcat and subdomain

Tags: tomcat, subdomain

I have a Tomcat 8 web server serving an application at http://alarcosj.esi.uclm.es/ctwebplus/

I'd like to make it accesible through: http://ctwebplus.alarcosj.esi.uclm.es/

Do you know what should I change in Tomcat configuration to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a sub-domain with your registrar.